# C# Regular Expression for x number of groups of A-Z separated by hyphen

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the following pattern.

A minimum of 3 'groups' of alphanumeric characters separated by a hyphen.

Eg: ABC1-AB-B5-ABC1

Each group can be any number of characters long.

I have tried the following:

```
^(\w*(-)){3,}?$
```

This gives me what I want to an extent.

ABC1-AB-B5-0001 fails, and ABC1-AB-B5-0001- passes.

I don't want the trailing hyphen to be a requirement.

I can't figure out how to modify the expression.

Comment: Just have a terminating group that doesn't have the hyphen.

Comment: @Neill Is your e.g. pattern fixed. Will it always be like the one you mentioned or it can change? E.g.: ABC1-AB-B5-0001-AB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^(\w*(-)){3,}?$` pattern even allows a string like `-----` because the only required pattern here is a hyphen: `\w*` may match **0** word chars. The `-` may be both leading and trailing because of that.

You may use

```
\A\w+(?:-\w+){2,}\z
```

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (that is, letters, digits or `_` symbols)
- `(?:-\w+){2,}` - 2 or more sequences of:

  - `-` - a single hyphen
  - `\w+` -  1 or more word chars
- `\z` - the very end of string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3A-%5Cw%2B%29%7B2%2C%7D%5Cz&i=ABC1-AB-B5-0001).

Or, if you do not want to allow `_`:

```
\A[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+){2,}\z
```

or to only allow ASCII letters and digits:

```
\A[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+){2,}\z
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this:

```
^\w+-\w+-\w+(-\w+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\w+-){2,}(\w+)-?$
```

Matches 2+ groups separated by a hyphen, then a single group possibly terminated by a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

`((?:-?\w+){3,})`

Matches minimum 3 groups, optionally *starting* with a hyphen, thus ignoring the trailing hyphen.

Note that the `\w` word character also select the underscore char `_` as well as `0-9` and `a-z`

[link to demo](https://regex101.com/r/U8vb5l/1)